# Would my question fit on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to know:

Why do people repeat certain typing mistakes?

I'm from Lebanon, the "Lebanese" way of saying yes is "eh", people keep making the same mistake, typing "rh", never ever "wh", I wonder why and there's stats on that subject.

Would my question be on topic?

Comment: No it would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Almost certainly not

As mentioned in the [Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this site is almost exclusively for "challenging unreferenced notable claims". It is not a site for obtaining stats on arbitrary subjects. It's possible you could find a relevant notable claim, and then the answers to that question might contain information you wanted, but that seems extremely unreliable (and I don't consider such an attempt to be a good idea by any metric).

I personally think it's unlikely that there is a lot of research specifically in the area of "Lebanese typos", so I think that you might be unable to get an answer no matter where you ask unless you put in additional effort to draw conclusions from studies in other languages. Regardless, I can think of two alternate StackExchange sites that might fit the question better:

- [User Experience.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) mainly comes at questions from the perspective of a software developer trying to fix a problem, but statistics about typos are certainly relevant and somebody there might be able to help you.
- [Superuser.SE](https://superuser.com/) has a broader focus, but also has numerous questions related to typos so might be able to help.

In either case, you might get the best results by starting in the site's main chat room for quick and casual guidance such as how the question should be phrased.

Comment: Just for the records, I'm not interested in the Lebanese dialects, I want to know if people have tendencies to type a certain way or fix some mistakes while ignoring others, I mean, maybe if people were to write `wh` then they would fix it since it's the first letter and they pay attentions to first letters, I'm just making up a nonsense meaningless example just to showcase why i asked the question. I was inspired by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPCpXXBHFSA and the research done on "WASD"

Comment: Although my subject and WASD are different, I'm interested to know if humans have distinct behaviors or characteristics when typing